# [UIRefreshControl setRefreshControlState:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, dealloc, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` as a subview of a `UICollectionView`. My problem is that the selector I added as target of the refreshControl is being called after the viewController is deallocated. Here is how I'm setting up the refreshControl.

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshMedia:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
[self.collectionView setBounces:YES];
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

And in the dealloc I've tried to put this:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    self.collectionView.delegate = nil;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = nil;
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.refreshControl removeTarget:self action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = nil;
}
```

Here's my error message:

```
-[UIRefreshControl setRefreshControlState:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x178e52a0
```